# Let $\ell^0=\{\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \mid a_n=0 \text{ for } n\gg1\}$ and $f:\ell^0 \to C$ show that $f$ is linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $$\ell^0=\{\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \mid a_n=0 \text{ for } n\gg1\}$$ and $f : \ell^0 \to C$ with $f(\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\mathbb{\infty} na_n$

Show that $f$ is linear map that is not continuous

Could anyone help me showing this?

Comment: Have you been able to show it is linear? Just remember that since there are only finitely many terms in the sum you can split the sum as you like.

Comment: Concerning the continuity (or not) of $f$, which topology are you considering on $\ell^0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the norm on $\ell^0$, I will go ahead and assume it is the supremum norm.

The linearity is easy to check, Surb's answer shows how to do that calculation.

For the second question, recall that for linear functions, linearity is equivalent to boundedness on the unit sphere. Now let's pick $e^n \in \ell^0$ the canonical unit vectors (i.e. $e^n_i = \delta_{in}$ where $\delta$ denotes the Kronecker-delta).

It holds that $\vert\vert e^n \vert \vert_{\infty} = 1$, but $f(e^n)=n$. Hence it follows that:

$$ \sup_{\vert\vert v \vert\vert_{\infty}=1} f(v) = \infty$$

This shows that $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: $l^0$ is the space of zero sequences

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ s.t. $a_n=0$ for all $n>m$ and $p$ s.t. $b_n=0$ for all $n>p$

$$f(\alpha\{a_n\}+\beta\{b_n\})=\alpha\sum_{n\geq 1}na_n+\beta\sum_{n\geq 1}nb_n=\alpha\sum_{n=1}^m na_n+\beta\sum_{n=1}^p nb_n=\alpha f(\{a_n\})+\beta f(\{b_n\})$$